# What is the ethereum transaction data structure?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, calldata

I'd like to know the detail of the Ethereum transaction data structure.
What data is stored in transaction?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An Ethereum transaction - as in, what you pass to `sendRawTransaction()` - consists of the following fields, in order and RLP-encoded (note that the field names are not part of the encoded data):

- **nonce** - transaction sequence number fr the sending account
- **gasprice** - price you are offering to pay
- **startgas** - maximum amount of gas allowed for the transaction
- **to** - destination address (account or contract address)
- **value** - eth to transfer to the destination, if any
- **data** - all of the interesting stuff goes here
- **v** - along with **r** and **s** makes up the ECDSA signature
- **r**
- **s**

Any payload, whether raw data or a contract function signature and parameters, is encoded into the **data** field.

Some references:

[Transaction (python)](https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm/blob/v0.4.0-alpha.4/eth/rlp/transactions.py#L58-L68)

[LegacyTx (go)](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.10.8/core/types/legacy_tx.go#L25-L34)

[rlp.Serializable (python)](https://github.com/ethereum/pyrlp/blob/develop/rlp/sedes/lists.py#L135)

[ECDSA parameters](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38351/ecdsa-v-r-s-what-is-v)

Comment: Is a message structure same as a transaction structure?

Comment: The message structure is the only thing that is formally specified. The "data structure" representing a transaction is a construct of the application in which it exists (and therefore to some extent the programming language.) For instance, it is very unlikely that `geth`, `eth` and `pyethapp` use - or even _could_ use - the exact same internal data structure to represent a transaction.

Comment: but what is 'data' field? what sort of interesting stuff goes there? Could you provide any example for the data part?

Comment: @AbhishekDeb "interesting" here means arguments to a smart contract.  If you're calling a smart contract function, or creating a smart contract, all of that code gets lumped into the data field.

Answer (score 4):

you can check a transsaction by its hash, for instance in eth :

```
> web3.eth.getTransaction('0xc5eee3ae9cf10fbee05325e3a25c3b19489783612e36cb55b054c2cb4f82fc28')
{
  blockHash: '0xdb85c62ef50103f08e9220b59d6c08cbfb52e61d84926dedb3fe9b6940e6bbea',
  blockNumber: 290081,
  from: '0x1dcb8d1f0fcc8cbc8c2d76528e877f915e299fbe',
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 50000000000',
  hash: '0xc5eee3ae9cf10fbee05325e3a25c3b19489783612e36cb55b054c2cb4f82fc28',
  input: '0x',
  nonce: 34344,
  to: '0x702bd0d370bbf0b97b66fe95578c62697c583393',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 5000111390000000000'
}
```

which you can see in a blockchain scanner [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc5eee3ae9cf10fbee05325e3a25c3b19489783612e36cb55b054c2cb4f82fc28)

Comment: Does raw transaction data have signature in it?

Answer (score 3):

As of *London fork*, a new EIP-2718 transaction is introduced with `TransactionType` 2, as described in [ethereum/EIPs/eip-1559](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md).

The new payload structure -

`rlp([chain_id, nonce, max_priority_fee_per_gas, max_fee_per_gas, gas_limit, destination, amount, data, access_list, signature_y_parity, signature_r, signature_s])`

### Specification

Block validity is defined in the reference implementation below.
The `GASPRICE` (`0x3a`) opcode **MUST** return the `effective_gas_price` as defined in the reference implementation below.

The intrinsic cost of the new transaction is inherited from EIP-2930, specifically `21000 + 16 * non-zero calldata bytes + 4 * zero calldata bytes + 1900 * access list storage key count + 2400 * access list address count`.

The EIP-2718 `TransactionPayload` for this transaction is `rlp([chain_id, nonce, max_priority_fee_per_gas, max_fee_per_gas, gas_limit, destination, amount, data, access_list, signature_y_parity, signature_r, signature_s])`.

The `signature_y_parity, signature_r, signature_s` elements of this transaction represent a secp256k1 signature over `keccak256(0x02 || rlp([chain_id, nonce, max_priority_fee_per_gas, max_fee_per_gas, gas_limit, destination, amount, data, access_list]))`.

The EIP-2718 `ReceiptPayload` for this transaction is `rlp([status, cumulative_transaction_gas_used, logs_bloom, logs])`.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction consists of following field while validating it into the block:

```
Status
Block
TimeStamp
From
To
Value
Transaction fees
Gas Price
Gas Limit & Usage by Txn
Gas Fees
Burnt & Txn Savings Fees
Input Data
Others (Tx type, Nonce, Position)
```

You can track all this when you create and deploy the contract on etherscan.io

Comment: The status is not part of the transaction, it is in the transaction receipt. Etherscan shows several fields that are useful for their users, but they aren't part of the transaction.

Comment: Ahh got it, thanks for clarifying. I just started learning about Blockchain and Ethereum.