# Understanding serialized unsigned raw transaction

Tags: raw-transaction, rlp

I'm currently learning about RLP ([ethereum-under-the-hood-part-ii](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-under-the-hood-part-ii-i-933411deebe1), [wiki-eth-rlp](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP)) and Ethereum transaction structure, my goal is to create an unsigned raw tx and then sign it.

Right now I'm playing around with code snipped which I assume are working such as [raw_tx_demo](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/code/web3js/raw_tx/raw_tx_demo.js) which produces:

- RLP-Encoded Tx: **0xe6808609184e72a0008303000094b0920c523d582040f2bcb1bd7fb1c7c1ecebdb3480801c8080**
- Tx Hash: **0x3a2fd1a5ea9ffee477f449be53a49398533d2c006a5815023920d1c397298df3**

Given [ethereum tx structure](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/what-is-the-ethereum-transaction-data-structure), below what I extract from the *RLP-Encoded Tx*:

```
0x {e6} {80} {86 09 18 4e 72 a0 00} {83 03 00 00} {94 b0 92 0c 52 3d 58 20 40 f2 bc b1 bd 7f b1 c7 c1 ec eb db 34} {80} {80} {1c} {80} {80}

{e6} - ?: 230
{80} - nonce: 0
gasPrice: 10000000000000
gasLimit: 196608
to: "0xb0920c523d582040f2bcb1bd7fb1c7c1ecebdb34"
{80} - value: 0
{80} - data: 0
{1c} - v: 28
{80} - r: 0
{80} - s: 0
```

From here, I got some questions:

- What the first byte `0xe6` or `230` is for ? How is it computed ?
- Why does the ChainId is `0x1c` or `28` ? Given this [list](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/how-to-select-a-network-id-or-is-there-a-list-of-network-ids) it don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer.

> Why does the ChainId is 0x1c or 28 ? Given this list it don't understand.

The link you point to shows network ID, [which isn't the same as chain ID](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37533/what-is-a-chainid-in-ethereum-how-is-it-different-than-networkid-and-how-is-it?rq=1).

Further, `28` isn't the chain ID, it's the `v` value. See [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md#specification) for details of expected `v` values, and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/what-does-v-r-s-in-eth-gettransactionbyhash-mean) answer for a definition of `v`, `r`, and `s`.

Answer (score 2):

The byte 0xe6 was simply following the [3rd rule](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-under-the-hood-part-ii-i-933411deebe1) describing an rlp list serialized.

```
tx = new ethTx({});
console.log('RLP-Encoded Tx: 0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex'))
```

Gives: **0x c9 808080808080808080** and as the payload **808080808080808080** is 9 bytes or 0x09 so below 55 bytes, serializing a rlp list is just 0xc0 + 0x09 -> **0xc9**.

In my exemple, the payload was 38 bytes or 0x26 and 0xc0 + 0x26 -> **0xe6**